# Visiting required file from .emacs

Tags: file, emacs, input, require

Is it possible to visit a mentioned file in require like:

```
    (require 'key-chord)
```

For which when clicking on "key-chord" (or some other input than clicking), makes you visit that file?

EDIT: Given that we want to visit the file "key-chord.el"

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. It took me several attempts to understand it, but I think you're asking for a way to look at the source file of what ever X is in `(require 'X)`?

Comment: But to make it a broader question, I suppose in case it is not finding a X.el, it should indeed visit the file of function X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the cursor on whatever is being required, e.g. the "k" in "key-chord", and do `M-x ffap RET RET`.  `ffap` is an alias for `find-file-at-point`, which understands `require`, at least in lisp-mode.  I have `ffap` bound to `C-x f`, because I rarely have use for that key's default binding.

Some Emacs installations don't have the .el files (only the .elc files).  In Debian/Ubuntu, you need to install a separate package to get them (emacs-*version*-el, IIRC).

Comment: I recorded it as a macro with calling M-x ffap RET RET, then binding it to your suggested C-x f

Answer (score 1):

`locate-library` tells you the file name, and `find-file` opens the file in a buffer for editing.  (You might want `find-file-read-only` if you merely want to inspect it.)

```
(find-file (locate-library "key-chord.el" t))
```

You can turn it into a function, something like this:

```
(defun find-locate-library (lib)
  "Visit the source for library LIB in a buffer."
  (let ((location (locate-library (concat lib ".el") t)))
    (if location
      (find-file location)
     (message "Could not find library %s" lib)) ))
```

How to hook this into a viewing or editing buffer is a separate topic.  I suppose you could amend Elisp mode to make library names clickable, but I cannot tell off-hand how to do that.

Thanks to @Deokhwan Kim for the suggestion to limit search to ".el" files only.

Comment: `(find-file (locate-library (concat "key-chord" ".el") t))` would be a little better in order to make sure that `.el` will be visited rather than `.elc`.

Comment: The question I ask is different. I want "key-chord" to be opened in a buffer for editing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Works for me; doesn't it for you?  @Deokhwan Kim's suggestion is a good improvement, though.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> prompts you for the name of a library, and then visits that file.

Calling it with point on a valid library name will make that the default prompt value.

Calling it with point *anywhere* within a `require` statement will also do the right thing.

I use `find-library` frequently, and bind it to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>C-l</kbd> for convenience.